# How to redirect a page for external links except social links

Tags: javascript, http-redirect

I have a Blogger blog and i want to keep track of exxternal links by making a redirect page with javascript for all links except internal links and social links.

I know how to do it like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("aLinkId").addEventListener("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// Here we redirect to the wanted page, with the extra parameter, with the original external URL
location.href = "REDIRECT-PAGE-URL?redirect=" + document.getElementById("aLinkId").href; 
}); };
```

But that doesn't work in blogger links don't have id, i'd have to put it for every link.

but for the redirect page, I'm stuck.

Comment: what do the blogger links look like? You can use a more generic selector than id to get the links and loop through them all.

Comment: just a link with no id '<a href="link" target="blank">text</a>'

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the links using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) and then loop through each link and add an event listener on them. This way does not depend on each link having a unique ID.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let href = this.href
      console.log(href);
      //location.href = "REDIRECT-PAGE-URL?redirect=" + href;
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<a href="url1" target="blank">link1</a>
<a href="url2" target="blank">link2</a>
<a href="url3" target="blank">link3</a>
<a href="url4" target="blank">link4</a>
```